# ring isomorphism in the complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a ring isomorphism for which $f(x) = x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.  Prove that $f$ is either the identity mapping ($\mathrm{id}:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$) or f maps each $a + bi \in \mathbb{C}$ to its complex conjugate $a – bi$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** We have $-1=f(-1)=f(i^2)=(f(i))^2$.